# How can i Redirect customer to "Register" page if use email address and password is wrong?

Tags: magento, redirect, authentication, passwords, magento-1.7

i am new in magento
i want to redirect customer to "Register" page when customer click on 
log in button if user email address and password is not match
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload the relevant controller which is  app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

In order to do so, follow that guide : 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller

Then, in your module's AccountController.php class, overload the loginPostAction() method and add the following line where relevant, to redirect the customer to the registration page :

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/create');
```

Answer (score -3):

Just Goto app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

In the function: protected function _loginPostRedirect() add your redirect url for the wrong username and password validation.

Comment: Never, i repeat, Never change something in Magento core files... Always create an override or your update-capabilities are gone!